# How to synchronize two nested jquery foreach loop?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have two nested for each loops at the last iteration of the inner loop i want to call a jquery function which contain an ajax call. Only after getting the result from this ajax call next iteration of the outer for each should happen. Is there any way to synchronize these loops.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        dataType:'json',
        url: 'getCall1',
        data: JSON.stringify(send_data),
        success: function(json)
        {
          $.each(json,function(i,item){
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                    dataType:'json',
                    url: 'getcall2',
                    data: JSON.stringify(send_data),
                    success: function(json)
                    {
                      $.each(json,function(i,item){
                       //For last iteration of this loop i want to call a function contain another ajax call. After completion of this call i want to continue with next iteration of outer loop
                        callFun();
                      });
                    }
             });
      });
   }

});

function callFun(){
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        dataType:'json',
        url: 'getcall3',
        data: JSON.stringify(send_data),
        success: function(json)
        {

        }
  });
}
```

Comment: You should understand how it will affect your performance. Several nested AJAX calls will take much time to execute.

Comment: I am able to get the result as fast but the problem is that two loops are not waiting for the function call 'callFun'

Comment: I think people are missing the implied question, which you've only specified in code comments: `For last iteration of this loop i want to call a function contain another ajax call. After completion of this call i want to continue with next iteration of outer loop`

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it using callback functions:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "getCall1",
    data: JSON.stringify(send_data),
    success: function(json)
    {
        var keys = Object.keys(json);
        if(keys.length)
        {
            func1(0, keys, json);
        }
    }

});

function func1(index, keys, json1)
{
    //you can get values from json1 using:
    var val = json1[keys[index]];
    //and use val
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "getcall2",
        data: JSON.stringify(send_data),
        success: function(json2)
        {
            var keys2 = Object.keys(json2),
                i;
            if(keys2.length)
            {
                for(i = 0; i < keys2.length; i++)
                {
                    //do as you wish
                    if(i === (keys2.length - 1))
                    {
                        callFun(
                            function callBack()
                            {
                                if(index < keys.length)
                                {
                                    func1(++index, keys, json1);
                                }
                            }
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

function callFun(callbackFunc)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "getcall3",
        data: JSON.stringify(send_data),
        success: function(json)
        {
            callbackFunc();
        }
    });
}
```

Good Luck

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery promises or deferred Object, which will be best fit for your problem. Make sure all these Ajax are Asynchronous. Please try like this:

```
     var promiseOne, promiseTwo,promiseThree;
        // Promises
        promiseOne = $.ajax({ url: 'getCall1' });

        promiseTwo = $.ajax({ url: 'getcall2' });

        promiseThree=$.ajax({ url: 'getcall3' });

     $.when(promiseOne).done(function(jsonValue1){
       $.each(jsonValue1,function(value1){
          $.when(promiseTwo).done(function(jsonValue2){
            $.each(jsonValue2,function(value2){
              $.when(promiseThree).done(function(jsonValue3){
               $.each(jsonValue3,function(value3){

                //write the code here

           })
            })
          })
        })
      })

 });
```

Comment: I want to pass two json values via getcall2 and getcall3 where should i specify that.

Comment: You dont need all this nesting, as the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) specify, `when` can take multiple promises and resolves when *all* are done. You also missed the point of the question: `For last iteration of this loop i want to call a function contain another ajax call. After completion of this call i want to continue with next iteration of outer loop`

Comment: In ajax Async. call, you have to wait for complete the call and get data and use it, otherwise you will get 'Undefined'.